# How to copy text after line count?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Summary: Can I start copying at the third count of text and stop at the fourth count of that instance?

I have some Windows eventlog files that I need to import into our event manager program, but they're not compatible currently. My log has a header that is surrounded by asterisks and I was trying to count the lines of asterisks and start copying after the third line. I then want to import the text into another file.

I also want to stop copying when the 4<sup>th</sup> line of asterisks is encountered as this symbolizes the end of the information I need.

Sorry this is worded so oddly. What I have tried before is below. The lines commented out are what I have tried but haven't worked for me.

Example of header:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Log
* Date/Time Generated: 10/30/2013   12:01 AM
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Code:

```psh
#$log = Get-Content -Path .\filepath
#$asterisk = "* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"
#$count = Measure-Object -Line $asterisk

#ForEach ($line in $log){
#DO
#{
#  DO{
#  $log | Add-Content .\filepath\test.txt
#  }until($count -eq 4)


#}until($count -eq 4)}

#$LogFile = Get-Content -Path .\filepath
$Asterisks = Get-Content -Path .\filepath | Select-String -Pattern "\* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \* \*"

#DO
#{
#  DO{
#  $Asterisks.Matches.Count
#  Get-Content -Path .\filepath
#  }While($Asterisks.Matches.Count -eq 3)

$Asterisks|Add-Content .\filepath
#}while($Asterisks.Matches.Count -eq 3)
```

Comment: Are there multiple instances of that set of header lines in the same file, and you're trying to separate them?

Comment: Not the header, but there are instances of the asterisks in between log types. There are about 3500 lines after the header and then there is another pair of lines with the asterisks again followed by another 2000 lines or so. I don't want those extra 2000 lines.

Answer (score 1):

I am understanding your need differently based on your comment. Using a similar style of sample as KevinD I assumed something similar to this.

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Log
* Date/Time Generated: 10/30/2013 12:01 AM
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Data you want
More data you want
...
oodles of it even
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Data you don't want
More data you REALLY dont want
...
so much crap
...
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

You want the text in between the sets of double asterisks lines. Lets play with some simple regex. This requires at least PowerShell 3.0 (Can be adjusted if need be)

```psh
# PowerShell 3.0+
$log = Get-Content -Path .\filepath -Raw
# PowerShell 2.0
$log = (Get-Content -Path .\filepath) -join "`r`n"
$asteriskLine = '\*( \*){38}'
If($log -match ("(?sm){0}`r`n{0}(.*?){0}`r`n{0}" -f $asteriskLine)){
   $Matches[1]
}
```

Which would match

```
Data you want
More data you want
...
oodles of it even
```

`$asteriskLine` is me trying to tidy up the long string that you had as well as fix the need to manually escape all those characters. I just build a string and convert it to an array so that I can join it again with spaces delimiting it.

What the regex was designed to do is gather the text that occurs after the first *set* of asterisks lines up until the next set. In an effort to make the regex a little easier to read we use the format operator so that we do not have to have a long string full of escaped `\*`.

Using `-match` is a simple way to test for the match and get the result with `$Matches[1]` as the data is contained in the capture group `(.*?)`

**Note on inefficiency**

Using `Get-Content` on such a large file in this way is considered very inefficient. However the code I present should be straightforward to understand. You could also looking into `StreamReader` and setting flags for when you see groups of asterisks. All depends on your needs and patience.

**Update from comments**

It is possible that *maybe* Ansgar had a good idea :) with how to make `$asteriskLine` simpler. Not even sure why it didn't occur to me.

**StreamReader**

I don't use this much as I am not playing with large files. Assuming that your log *really does* look like my example above this *should* work just fine.

```psh
$filePath = "c:\temp\text.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\temp\outputfile.txt"
$asteriskLine = '\*( \*){38}'
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg $filePath
[boolean]$flagReadData = $False
$asteriskRepeatCount = 0

while ($line = $file.ReadLine()) {
    # Check if this line is an astericks 
    If($line -match $asteriskLine){
        # Raise the astericks count
        $asteriskRepeatCount++

        # Check to see if we have found
        If ($asteriskRepeatCount -eq 2){
            # We have just found 2 repeating lines of $asteriskLine. Check the readData flag
            If($flagReadData){
                # We have hit the end of the stream and we can stop.
                $flagReadData =  $False
                break
            } Else {
                # Start recording the lines.
                $flagReadData =  $true
            }

            # Reset the count. 
            $asteriskRepeatCount = 0
        }

    } Else {
        # Current line does not match. Reset the count.
        $asteriskRepeatCount = 0
    }

    # Pass line if criteria are met. 
    If($asteriskRepeatCount -eq 0 -and $flagReadData -and $line -notmatch $asteriskLine){
        $line | Add-Content $outputFile
    }
}
$file.close()
```

Basically it reads each line of the file one at a time. Script maintains a count of the asterisks lines that it encounters sequentially. When it finds two the first time a boolean flag is set. While that flag is true then it outputs all lines that it reads. When it finds the next set of double asterisks lines then it stops reading the file.

Comment: I don't know what regex is (googling now), but if I left it sloppy and just used my current escape process would I still be able to use the if? Or is the IF part of 3.0. I only have powershell version 2.0 right now.

Comment: @skcuf It's the `-Raw` that is 3.0. Will make an edit. Is that what you file looks like?

Comment: Yes, That's what it looks like. Sorry, meant to say that.

Comment: @skcuf In case you didnt see it I put up the change that will work in 2.0

Comment: I think `$asteriskLine = '\*( \*){38}'` might be a little more readable than `$asteriskLine = [regex]::escape([char[]]("*" * 39) -join " ")`. ;)

Comment: How would I use StreamRadar? Get-Content seems to take forever and if there's a more efficient way to do it I definitely want to. I have to run through like 6gb of files...

Comment: Also, where would I put the part about putting the data into another file? Like test.txt or something.

Comment: @skcuf If you wanted to export the data you would just put something like `$Matches[1] | Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt`. I will try and create a streaming example. It would most likely be more efficient by not using regex.

Comment: Did that and all that was put in the test was a single *

Comment: If I was right about the file then both of my examples above work. You might need to do a little debugging for me as I don't have your input file.  @skcuf

Comment: The above worked for a single file but when I put *.log it told me there was an illegal character. Is there a way to do an entire directory for only .log files?

Comment: When you say the above... which part? also if you have multiple files then you we need to wrap this as a function. I can have a quick update for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, your log files look like this:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Log
* Date/Time Generated: 10/30/2013 12:01 AM
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Data you want
More data you want
...
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Data you don't want
More data you don't want
...
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Log
* Date/Time Generated: 10/30/2013 12:02 AM
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Second set of data you want
...
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
...
```

Assuming this is correct, and that you want all data to be saved to the same file, this should do it:

```
$log = Get-Content -Path .\filepath
$asterisk = "* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"
$count = 0

foreach ($line in $log) {
    If ($count -eq 3 -and $line -ne $asterisk) {
        $line | Add-Content .\filepath\test.txt
    }

    If ($line -eq $asterisk) {
        $count++
    }

    If ($count -eq 4) {
        $count = 0
    }

}
```

If I misunderstood, and you just want the first set of data, replace "$count = 0" with "break".

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Matt's because it's RegEx based, but I'll just split the file based on asterisk lines, remove blank results, skip the first result (Log and Date/Time lines) and select only the next item (which given the sample Matt was using should be exactly what you need). We will again be using the `-Raw` parameter in v3+ or you can `-Join` it all with new lines creating a multi-line string the hard way if you're using v2.

```
(Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.log -raw) -split "(?m)^\*(?: \*){38}"|?{!([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_))}|Select -skip 1 -first 1
```

Or in v2...

```
(Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.log) -join "`r`n" -split "(?m)^\*(?: \*){38}"|?{!([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_))}|Select -skip 1 -first 1
```

Either way, based on Matt's sample, you get:

> Data you want
>    More data you want
>   ...
>   oodles of it even

Now you can pipe that to `Set-Content` and output it to a file, or assign it to a variable, or whatever.

If your log is very large, and you know for sure that your data will be in the first, say 1000 lines or so, you may want to consider using the `-TotalCount` parameter for the `Get-Content` cmdlet. That would change the beginning of the line to:

```
(Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.log -raw -totalcount 1000)
```

That will only read the first 1000 lines, and if all you're interested is the beginning of the file that could speed things up considerably. But again, that is only an option if you know for sure that your data is within the first X lines of the file.

Comment: I get an error saying [system.string] doesn't contain a method named 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'

Comment: Ah, you must run an old version of PowerShell. Try `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)` instead. I forgot the Whitespace option wasn't included until v3 I think.

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not say it, I consider in my answer that all data you want to copy into some other file **do not start with an asterisk**. If it does, no problem, you can just tweak the `$rx`a little bit to match a different requirement.

Considering these conditions, the code you need is very simple. Firsy define the initial variables:

```
$file,$rx,$flag=
    'c:\...\CrapLog.log',
    '\s*\*+',
    $false
```

It's very simple.

Now, use this **ONE-LINER**:

```
switch -r -f($file){$rx{if($flag){break}else{continue}}default{$flag=$true;$_}}
```

Alright, if you want to see the one-liner laid out in more lines, see it here:

```
switch -r -f($file){
    $rx{if($flag){break}else{continue}}
    default{$flag=$true;$_}
}
```

That's it.

By the way, the code above will output **all lines you're wanting**, and you can include them in another file (as you wish).

Why code many,many lines, if you can do it with much less typing? 
After all, this is scripting.

**The `switch` statement is very powerful...**

**ADDED simplification to the switch statement:**

`switch -r -f($file){
    $rx{if($flag){break}}
    default{$flag=$true;$_}
}`

**The `switch` statement is really powerful...**

**ADDED example to write the output to anotherfile:**

```
$file,$rx,$flag=
    'c:\...\example.txt',
    '\s*\*+',
    $false

$fileOUT='c:\...\excerpt.txt'

$lines=switch -r -f($file){
    $rx{if($flag){break}}
    default{$flag=$true;$_}
}

$lines >$fileOUT
```

where `example.txt` could be something like this:

```
********************************
* Company Contoso
********************************
********************************
I want this line 1
I want this line 2
I want this line 3
I want this line 1000 (or even more)
********************************
I DON'T want this line and any other below this one: 1
I DON'T want this line and any other below this one: 2
********************************
I DON'T want this line and any other below this one: 3
********************************
********************************
I DON'T want this line and any other below this one: 4
I DON'T want this line and any other below this one: 5
********************************
```

Comment: What does switch do? Could you put some explanations down there. I'm trying to write a script and haven't written a script before so some explanation of what is happening would be great.  Is there a way to pipe this into another file?

Comment: Yes, I can tell you many things about the `switch` statement, but the PSTeam can do it much better than me: help about_switch.

Comment: I edit my post and wrote an example to write the output to anotherfile. Note that you can append the data, instead of overwriting the file's content.